# Google Event tracking for phone number

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am running a WordPress site, which is verified with Google Webmaster Tools and has a GA code associated with Google Analytics.

I've done some research on the web to add an Event tracker for clickable phone numbers in mobile, so that I can measure how many people actually use the phone number on the homepage of the website we developed for a client: posanarestaurant.com.

Most of the blogs that offered up how to do this simply gave me this code to add to my site below:

`<a href="tel:18285053969" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Phone Call Tracking','Click/Touch','Home Banner']);">828.505.3969</a>`

They said that Google would start to pick up tracking in 24 to 48-hours, but I haven't seen anything in GA yet.

I know that there is some javascript that might go in the head of the site, but one of the plugins I'm using already adds that javascript, so I don't want to duplicate having two exact same javascript references in the head of the site.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might like to try installing the Tag Assistant addon in Google Chrome which will show you whether your event is actually firing.

Comment: Are you using classic GA or Universal Analytics? The syntax of your code is for the former.

Comment: I'm using universal analytics. Okay, so that's the issue then. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for UA event tracking is

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking', 'Click/Touch', 'Home Banner')
```

So your complete code would be

```
<a href="tel:18285053969" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Tracking', 'Click/Touch', 'Home Banner');">828.505.3969</a>
```

Once you have that set, and if you are not filtering out your own views, you can check for the event hit in Real-Time reports (so you don't have to wait 24 hours to see if it's working).

Comment: Okay, this is great. I can't vote up because I don't have enough reputation yet, but many thanks.

Comment: No problem, you should be able to close off the ticket though by accepting it.

Comment: I did set up my Google Tag Manager and am going to add the tag I set up as recommended, after the Body tag, to listen for an Event > Click. Once I add the Tag Manager code and the GA syntax for UA event tracking, it should fire the event and register in GA.

Comment: Actually, if you have GTM on your site, then you don't really need to have any on-page code because GTM can do all the tracking. If you just leave the on-page code there, you will need to have the GA tracking snippet on your page as well so that tha ga library is recognised.

Comment: I added the tracking code you suggested and it started firing events. Thanks so much for your help! (Did not add Google Tag Manager yet–going to test that out on another site later).

Comment: Good to hear it's working. Best of success with your analytics!