# Google Analytics Phone Number Tracking in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to figure out how to add tracking with Google Analytics to multiple phone numbers on a Wordpress site. I saw [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848203/google-event-tracking-for-phone-number) from and earlier Stack Overflow post but I wasn't sure if it was up to date. I noticed somewhere else ([here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-google-analytics-event-tracking-in-wordpress/)) on a Google search that said you have to add an Event in your GA account first and then add that code. Is this correct? Or do you just have to add the code itself to the Wordpress site without adding an Event in GA?

Also, if it's code for a link, can I highlight the phone number and put the code into the link area (as in chain link in the Visual Editor) on the page, or do I have to place this code in the Text Editor part of the page?

I'm using the current UA right now.

Also, I'm really new to this event tracking stuff, so please accept my apologies if I stated/asked anything incorrectly. Thanks in advance for any and all feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to all your phone number instances within your HTML. *ie* `class="tel">`

Write a click function on that class, and then push the `ga` following the correct version syntax.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action');
```

**So:**

```
$('.tel').click(function() {
   ga('send', 'event', 'Category1', 'Action1', 'Demo!');
});
```

Comment: Hi, also this can be a good solution add this directly on the field with an onclick
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action');">Phone Number</>

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb, but do I put the syntax into the area where you would put the link? Or do I switch from Visual to Text and put the syntax in there as a link? Or do I have to put that somewhere else?

Comment: Okay, so I'm guessing by the no answer, that was a silly question here. But can you answer this one? Do I need to set up a custom Event in GA for either or both of these options? Thanks.

Comment: I think I get it now with your revised answer, Cam C. I assume I need to put that code into my functions.php file for each class instance that I apply in the html. I'll try that soon. Thank you.

Comment: Great Dan! If this helped you solve your problem, please mark the answer 'accepted' with the checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Tag Manager. It's great tool. There is also a plugin: DuracellTomi's Google Tag Manager for WordPress. You must read some documentation about GTM but when you will know GTM you can track almost anything on your site.

Comment: Thank you snecz. I will try this option if the other option doesn't work. I'm trying to avoid adding more plugins, but will if I can't figure out how to properly apply the other option.