# How to track a phone number on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a webpage with a phone number on it.

I want to be able to track how many people are clicking on that phone number.

How can I do this, please?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about analytics

Comment: Where do I post it then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Event tracking for phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28848203/google-event-tracking-for-phone-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track how many user clicked the link with phone number.
The sample link looks like:

```
<a onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'call', eventAction: 'click'});" href="tel:<YOUR-PHONE-NUMBER>" title="call me">Call Me</a>
```

And then in Google Analytics for instance you can create a new custom goal.

Go to: Your view->Goals->New Goal

And next do following steps:

- Goal setup: custom
- Goal description: name (for instance "Call me button"), type: event
- Goal details: Category setup as equal to "call", Action setup as equal to "click"
- Save

Comment: Brilliant! I knew you must be able to do it in Google analytics somehow but couldn't find any decent tutorials online. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Komito Analytics](https://komito.net/). It allows you to track CTAs such as a phone number clicks. See [integration page](https://komito.net/integration/) for more information.